# How to select the right method to apply to an object of a template type?

Tags: c++

I want to invoke some code like:

```
std::string invoke(auto &&x) {
  return to_string(x)
}
```

However, the right function to apply to `x` depends on the exact type of `x`. So I would need to write some code like:

```
if (the method invoke can apply on the obj x) {
  return invoke(x) 
} else (the method invoke 2 can apply on the obj x) {
  return invoke_2(x) 
} ... (Many methods are waited for the obj x of course)
```

I know I can use SFINAE to check if a given method can be applied to a function, but it's not convenient because I have to write quite a lot duplicate code for them.

Can I have some other ways to avoid any duplications?

---

So far I made this:

```
    template <typename F, typename... Args, typename = std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...))>> 
    std::true_type IsImpl(nullptr_t ); 

    template <typename...> 
    std::false_type IsImpl(...); 

    inline auto constexpr is_impl = [] (auto f) constexpr {
        return [] (auto &&... args) constexpr {
            return decltype(IsImpl<decltype(f), decltype(args)&&...>(nullptr)){}; 
        }; 
    }; 

        auto constexpr to_string_trait_invoke = [](auto &&a) constexpr -> decltype(to_string(a)) {
            return to_string(a); 
        }; 

// The running codes: 
        if constexpr (decltype(type_traits::is_impl(to_string_trait_invoke)(v))::value) {
            return to_string_trait_invoke(v); 
        }
```

It works successfully! When it has a matching `to_string()` method then it enters this branch, otherwise it fails and then selects the other branches. However, why does this work?

Comment: If you want to clarify a question then use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72465578/edit) button rather than raising a new one

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes but the previous one has been closed.

Comment: If you edit it then it can be reopened (if the duplicate doesn't still apply)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Okay, I get. Thanks for your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

```
if constexpr (requires{to_string(x);})
    return to_string(x);
else if constexpr (requires{to_string_2(x);})
    return to_string_2(x);
```

Note that you should probably use `decltype(x)(x)` instead of `x` to get perfect forwarding.

Comment: This is a good idea but two problems still exist: 
1. Duplicate codes exist. 
2. requires keyword isn't supported well in all compilers now.

Comment: @CutieDeng 1. Yep, apparently MSVC still can't handle `requires` outside of concepts... 2. You can't get less than two repetitions without macros.